# WPF binding two buttons together

Tags: wpf, button, binding

I work in Windows Presentation Foundation and I need to bind two buttons together. The first button is a classic button, the second is a toggle button. When the user presses the toggle button it becomes "ON" and in this very moment I need to disable the classic button. When the user presses the toggle button again and it becomes "OFF", the classic button should become "enabled". Is there any way to do this without a classic binding with converter. I mean triggers or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with triggers, but it'd be much more concise with a converter.  A triggers version would be something like this:

```
<Button Content="One">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=tb}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
<ToggleButton x:Name="tb">Two</ToggleButton>
```

With a suitable converter declared as a resource it'd be more like this:

```
<Button Content="One" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=tb, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}}" />
<ToggleButton x:Name="tb">Two</ToggleButton>
```